# GitHub Gist CSS

Tags: github, gist, hugo

I've embedded a GitHub Gist in a website for the first time, and am having some issues with how it appears. It seems like something in my Hugo theme's CSS is adding space above line 1 and below line 13.

The problematic display can be seen [here](https://slu-soc5050.github.io/week-08/#recodes-from-the-lecture).

Anyone have thoughts on how I could remove that space? I've never see a Gist render like this before for, nor can I find any questions on here that get at what I am seeing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gist-embed adds a class of `data` to the table container. It is used to customize the look of the embedded gist. Adjust your CSS selectors to fix the problem. I am sure you are inadvertently styling the `data` class directly, when in actuality you want to style a compound selector `article.data`.

Revisit your CSS code and adjust your selectors to reflect what you desire.

Comment: Thanks @Scriptonomy - finally had a chance to get back to this project. Your advice was super helpful!